# How can I use use "xsl:attribute" to set the src-URL for displaying an image?

Tags: html, xml, xslt

The code below does not show the image I want to display:

```
<img">
    <xsl:attribute name="src">
       <xsl:value-of select="//image"/>
       </xsl:attribute>
</img>
```

although the path to the image exists! Any idea what is wrong on this code?

Comment: Please edit the question and clean up your code. I don't think it really has asterisks and unmatched quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this

```
<img>
 <xsl:attribute name="src">
  <xsl:value-of select='imgsource'/>
 </xsl:attribute>
</img>
```

**BUT**

inside you xml there must be the path to the image with the variable imgsource, like this:

```
   <imgsource>http://www.test.com/Images/image.JPG</imgsource>
```

hence imgsource is like a variable not the path to the image.

Comment: You saved me so much time, Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

You can try do this with variable

```
<xsl:variable name="imgSrc" select="//image" />
<img src="$imgSrc" alt=""/>
```